# Loop through List with Linq condition

Tags: c#, linq, list

The code below works successfully to loop through a List. How do I add a where clause such that only for list items where sType = "File"

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
```

**Pseudo Code for what i want**

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Count.Where(y => y.sType == "File"); i++) // Loop through List with for
```

Comment: is there a reason to not foreach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use LINQ to obtain a new filtered List that only contains the items that fit your condition:

```
var filteredList = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Where(i => i.sType == "File").ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < filteredList.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
...
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to sjkm's answer, if you're not using the index, just use a foreach loop.

```
foreach(var item in MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Where(i => i.sType == "File"))
{
  // Do something with item.
}
```